# How to open a PDF attachment

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

Here is my problem: I have succesfully written a script to send a PDF attachment of a google worksheet. However, to print the file I have to open the attachment in the mail from the mailbox. I wonder whether it is possible to show the PDF directly after sending the email, so I can print is with File>Print command. Below is the part of the script that creates and sends the attachments:

```
var auth = "AuthSub token=\"" + AUTH_TOKEN + "\"";
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {headers: {Authorization: auth}});
var attachments = [{fileName:"GASgenerated.pdf", content: res.getContent(),  mimeType:"application/pdf"}];
MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {attachments:attachments});
```

So my question is: How can I open file "GASgenerated.pdf" in this script immediately after the MailApp.sendEmail command, so I can directly print the file?

Answer (score 0):

GAS will let you add browser side javascript: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service (This lets you create a google apps script webapp)

Example URL to download as PDF, you will need to change the spreadsheet key.
 https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=0AkGlO9jJLGO8dDB6Z19oSE5JZVZNdHFUa0RXM1dzaWc&exportFormat=pdf&gid=3&gridlines=0&printtitle=0&size=7&portrait=true&fitw=true

Comment: Thanks eddyparkinson, but I am unfortunately not very familiar with writing scripts (sorry for that). I have tried to understand, but I cannot figure out what you exactly mean. What I would like is to add printing statements  to the script above. Hope you can help me once again?

Comment: Do you know: Google spreadsheets have File->Print and File->Download As? ..... Or have you created a webapp. I feel like I am missing some details.